# Why do I get an error trying to call a template member function with an explicit type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I don't get it, it seems to me that the call to `f` is completely unambiguous, but it fails to compile with `expected primary-expression before ‘int’`. If I comment out the line with the call to `f`, it compiles fine.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    template<typename S>
    void f() { }
};

template<typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
    void g() {
        this->f<int>();
    }
};
```

Comment: I applaud you for not only finding this unholy problem but for never swearing once while describing it.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

This is due to a really obscure provision of the standard in which if you have a template that tries to access a template function in an object whose type depends on a template argument, you have to use the `template` keyword in a weird way:

```
this->template f<int>();
```

This is similar to the weirdness with `typename` that comes up with dependent types, except as applied to functions.  In particular, if you leave out the `template` keyword, there's a parsing ambiguity between

```
this->f<int>()
```

(what you intended), and

```
((this->f) < int) > ()
```

which makes no sense (hence your error).  The use of the keyword `template` here disambiguates and forces the compiler to recognize that it's looking at a perfectly valid call to a templated member function rather than a garbled mass of symbols.

Comment: I already knew a few syntax weirdnesses with templates, but I had never heard this one before.

Comment: @Gorpik: which is why you should avoid such things :)

Comment: @templatetypedef: do you know if any compiler diagnoses this correctly ? It would be interested to see if CLang (which claim a friendly diagnosis) would suggest the insertion of `template` as a Fix hint, unfortunately I don't have it handy.

Comment: Not only the answer is good, but it has the added bonus that it has been provided by a user named templatetypedef :-) He surely knows what he's talking about...

Comment: @Matthieu M.- This comes up so rarely that I've only seen it once and that was in g++, which had pretty uninstructive error messages.  If there is a compiler with a good diagnostic for this, I haven't seen it.

Comment: +1: I knew my bad knowledge of templates but that ! waw ! Good answer by "templatetypedef" with 42 badges ! A sign ;)

Comment: +1000 templatetypedef. And have mercy on your soul for even recognizing this problem and knowing what to do

Comment: Interestingly, Visual C++ 2010 doesn't treat this as an error, and compiles fine without the `template` keyword. Perhaps this has been improved in C++0x?

Comment: Visual Studio is a bit lax on some template features.  For example, it lets you omit typename in a few contexts where is technically required, and automatically imports names from template bases where it's not supposed to.  I'd be surprised if this was in C++0x and not just a quirk in VS.

Comment: @Pedro: it hasn't, Visual C++ is non compliant because it only checks the template at instantiation instead of two-phases look-up.

Comment: Wow, nutty! Thanks for the thorough answer :)

Comment: @Matthieu M.: So if non-compliance works better (in this case), what is gained?  Asking out of genuine curiosity.

Comment: @James: you lose early diagnosis of obvious errors (lack of `;`, name typo, etc...) and you get a mess in overload resolution (normally, only functions declared prior to the template should be considered, but with this VC++ you can have functions declared afterward taken into account which the writer of the template may not have anticipated)... I would say it definitely does not work better. However it's pretty stupid for a compiler to issue such a stupid warning (it makes no sense to compare with a type...), but then gcc has never been reknown for its user friendliness :/

Comment: Interestingly this happens for `A<T>::f<int>()` too, and the work around in that case is similar: `A<T>::template f<int>()`.

Comment: I liked C++, but the more I know this language, the more I find it badly designed...