# Multiplying 1xn Eigen::Array with 2xn Eigen::Array, with each column in the 1xn array behaving like a scalar

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have two `Eigen::Array` which have the same number of columns. One of them, `a`, has one row, and the other, `b`, has two rows.
What I want to do, is to multiply every column of `b` with the entry in the respective column in `a`, so that it behaves like this:

```
ArrayXXd result;
result.resizeLike(b);
for (int i=0; i<a.cols(); ++i)
    result.col(i) = a.col(i)[0] * b.col(i);
```

However, it's part of a rather long expression with several of such multiplications, and I don't want to have to evaluate intermediate results in temporaries. Therefore, I'd rather get an Eigen expression of the above, like

```
auto expr = a * b;
```

This, of course, triggers an assertion, because `a.rows() != b.rows()`.

What I tried, which works, is:

```
auto expr = a.replicate(2,1) * b;
```

However, the resulting code is very slow, so I hope there's a better option.

[Possibly related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63375963/eigen-conditiontype-array-efficient-way-to-broadcast-instead-of-looping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen provides the possibility to use [broadcasting](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html) for such cases. However, the one-dimensional array should first be converted into a Vector:

> broadcasting operations can only be applied with an object of type Vector

This will work in your case:

```
RowVectorXd av = a;  
ArrayXXd expr = b.rowwise() * av.array();
```

**Edit**

To avoid a copy of the data into a new vector one can use `Map`:

```
ArrayXXd expr = b.rowwise() * RowVectorXd::Map(&a(0), a.cols()).array();
```

Comment: Your code requires copying the array ```a``` into the row vector ```av```. Given that this is a performance critical section of the code, that is not really useful to me.

Comment: @RL-S I added a variant that does not require copying the array.

Comment: right, I forgot about ```Map```, good idea, I'll try that. But I think ```Map(a.data(),...)``` would be a bit cleaner there.

Comment: Yeah, using `.data()` is nice syntactic sugar. Doesn't really make a difference though. Since I am using primarily `Matrix` containers I am not immediately aware of all the member functions of the `Array` class.

Comment: With the edit, your answer solved my problem. Just one more question:
Do you know whether there's a difference between ```RowVectorXd::Map(...)``` and ```Map<RowVectorXd>(...)```?

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped. I believe that there is no difference between the two versions of `Map` that you mentioned. Maybe the developers of the Eigen library can say more about this. It would seem that `RowVectorXd::Map(...)` and `Map<RowVectorXd>(...)` behave in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the same solution to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63375963/eigen-conditiontype-array-efficient-way-to-broadcast-instead-of-looping) but here is my answer again:

- Define your arrays with fixed number of rows but dynamic number of columns whereas ArrayXXd type yields an array with both dynamic number of rows and columns.
- Use fixed-size version of operations. This should typically give faster code.